# while using drag and drop operation in jquery ui giving error

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

We are using

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scrollpane.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/tabs/js/tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tipsy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and when i try to use drag and drop

```
$("#move").draggable();
$("#pp-you").droppable({
  drop: function() { alert('dropped'); }
});
```

and when i try to drag it gives this error

```
 $.widget.prototype._trigger is undefined
return $.widget.prototype._trigger.call(this, type, event, ui);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and check your HTML/Javascript with Firebug.

```js
$("#move").draggable();

$("#pp-you").droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert('dropped');
  }
});
```

```css
#move {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#pp-you {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="move">try to move me</div>
<div id="pp-you">drop stuff here</div>
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/pZYnb/1/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: i think the problem is with the js file

Comment: the problem is with the tab.js file

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: right! I don't know much about this tab.js file so, I am afraid, I can't help.